# CloudFormation change set User not authorized

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I am trying to publish aws lambda to my client aws account however I keep getting this error message.

```
Error creating CloudFormation change set: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:user/testuser is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:CreateChangeSet on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:xxxx:stack/test-Stack/*
```

When i tested on my own account I have added my IAM user with a policy of "AdministratorAccess" which basically allow everything.

I checked the policies there is only "CloudFormationReadonlyAccess" but these does not allow write/delete. What policy should I ask my client to assign to the IAM user?

I have also try adding to my role

```
"cloudformation:CreateStack",
"cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
"cloudformation:ListStacks",
"cloudformation:UpdateStack",
"cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
"cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
"cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
"cloudformation:ValidateTemplate",
"cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
"cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet"
```

but the same error occur.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the resource on which these actions are allowed. To be specific

```
      - Action:
        - cloudformation:CreateStack
        - cloudformation:DeleteStack
        - cloudformation:UpdateStack
        - cloudformation:DescribeStacks
        - cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet
        - cloudformation:CreateChangeSet
        - cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet
        - cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet
        Effect: Allow
        Resource:
        - !Join
          - ':'
          - - arn
            - aws
            - cloudformation
            - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
            - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
            - !Join
              - /
              - - stack
                - test-stack
                - '*'
```

Also check the sts:AssumeRole service is cloudformation.amazonaws.com